# JQuery Validation in IE9 sets all the text fields as Required fields?

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-9, field, required

Jquery Validation in IE9 is setting all the text fields as Required. Can't find why?
In my form I have more fields Not Required. But when I click Submit, the class error is added to ALL the text fields included the Not Required.

Here are my rules:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
setFields();

var validator = $("#frmContact").validate({
        rules: {
            ddQuestions:"required",
            txtEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            txtName:{required: true, placeholder: true},
            txtPhone:'customphone',
            txtAddress: "required",
            txtCity:"required",
            ddStates:"required",
            txtMessage:"required",
            txtZipcode:{required:true,zipcodeUS:true},
        },
        messages: {
            captcha: "Correct captcha is required. Click the captcha to generate a new one",
            ddQuestions: "Please select a topic",
            txtName:{required:"Do not forget put your name", placeholder: "Do not forget put your name"},
            txtEmail:"Insert a valid email to be in contact",
            txtAddress:"Don't forget put your address",
            txtCity:"Please insert the city",
            ddStates:"Please select the state",
            txtMessage:"Don't forget put your message",
            txtZipcode:"Insert a valid zipcode",
        },
        ignore:":not(:visible)"
});
```

Comment: Is there an option to "force" some fields to be Optional? I know that by default all are optional, but, probably is I declare those fields works?